# using tsconfig-paths with es modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsconfig, ts-node, tsconfig-paths

I have a typescript project that uses commonjs modules, I use `ts-node` to run it, and `tsconfig-paths` to resolve `tsconfig.compilerOptions.paths` at runtime.

now I want my project to migrate to use es modules, so I made some changes:

- add `type: module` to package.json
- change `module: commonjs` to `ES2022` in tsconfig.json
- change the command `ts-node` into `node --loader ts-node/esm`

now all things are working perfectly, but it seems that `tsconfig-paths` doesn't work in esm.

minimal reproductions:

- [commonjs project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-42hfdu?file=index.ts)
- [es module project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-z4b52r?file=index.ts) that is forked from the commonjs one, but modified to use es modules

in both projects:

- run `npm run build` to test compiling with typescript with esm
- run `npm start` to test `ts-node`
- run `npm start:paths` to test `ts-node` with `tsconfig-paths`

Comment: The Node.js runtime analog of TypeScript's [path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) is [subpath imports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-imports).